# Page not shown correctly under Chrome

Tags: android

I tried to post data from my Android app to website, it works fine with firefox and other browsers; but it didn't work with Chrome. Chrome sometimes just show google home page i.e. www.google.com.

```
String finalUrl = "javascript:" + 
    "var to = 'http://mysite:8001/login.jsp';" +
    "var p = {login:'test',id:'test'};"+
    "var myForm = document.createElement('form');" +
    "myForm.method='post' ;" +
    "myForm.action = to;" +
    "for (var k in p) {" +
        "var myInput = document.createElement('input') ;" +
        "myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');" +
        "myInput.setAttribute('name', k) ;" +
        "myInput.setAttribute('value', p[k]);" +
        "myForm.appendChild(myInput) ;" +
    "}" +
    "document.body.appendChild(myForm) ;" +
    "myForm.submit() ;" +
    "document.body.removeChild(myForm) ;";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(finalUrl));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: you will need to provide more info what you did

Comment: Code posted in code block.